ungroup data frame by 1 column in r
    1.     2.   3.    4.    5.  6  
1  15      0    1     0     1   0
2  9       1    1     0     0   1

How can I change this in a way that I get 15 rows with 0 1 0 1 0 and 9 rows with 1 1 0 0 1?

If your data look like this:
df <- data.frame(x = c(15, 9),
                 v1 = c(0, 1),
                 v2 = c(1, 1),
                 v3 = c(0, 0),
                 v4 = c(1, 0),
                 v5 = c(0, 1))

#    x v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
# 1 15  0  1  0  1  0
# 2  9  1  1  0  0  1

If you want a tidyverse solution, you can use uncount in tidyr:
tidyr::uncount(df, x)

Or you can try this in base R:
df[rep(row.names(df), df$x), -1]

Both give the below (though row names are slightly different using base R)
#    v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
 # 1   0  1  0  1  0
 # 2   0  1  0  1  0
 # 3   0  1  0  1  0
 # 4   0  1  0  1  0
 # 5   0  1  0  1  0
 # 6   0  1  0  1  0
 # 7   0  1  0  1  0
 # 8   0  1  0  1  0
 # 9   0  1  0  1  0
 # 10  0  1  0  1  0
 # 11  0  1  0  1  0
 # 12  0  1  0  1  0
 # 13  0  1  0  1  0
 # 14  0  1  0  1  0
 # 15  0  1  0  1  0
 # 16  1  1  0  0  1
 # 17  1  1  0  0  1
 # 18  1  1  0  0  1
 # 19  1  1  0  0  1
 # 20  1  1  0  0  1
 # 21  1  1  0  0  1
 # 22  1  1  0  0  1
 # 23  1  1  0  0  1
 # 24  1  1  0  0  1


An alternative "manual" way using matrix
data.frame(do.call(rbind, apply(df, 1, \(x) 
  matrix(x[-1], x[1], length(x)-1, byrow=T))))
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1   0  1  0  1  0
2   0  1  0  1  0
3   0  1  0  1  0
4   0  1  0  1  0
5   0  1  0  1  0
6   0  1  0  1  0
7   0  1  0  1  0
8   0  1  0  1  0
9   0  1  0  1  0
10  0  1  0  1  0
11  0  1  0  1  0
12  0  1  0  1  0
13  0  1  0  1  0
14  0  1  0  1  0
15  0  1  0  1  0
16  1  1  0  0  1
17  1  1  0  0  1
18  1  1  0  0  1
19  1  1  0  0  1
20  1  1  0  0  1
21  1  1  0  0  1
22  1  1  0  0  1
23  1  1  0  0  1
24  1  1  0  0  1

